# In App Billing Require Separate User Accounts?

Tags: android, billing

I have an application currently in development utilising user logins linked to an SQL database.

When utilising google's in app purchases, does google have its own system of logging who has made purchases, from what i understand, it appears purchases are assigned to a users google account id's. Am i correct in thinking so? And as a result i would not need to log them separately to verify purchases?

Comment: In-app purchases are tied to Google logins. Google's payment system knows nothing about your own login system. There's a merchant interface where transactions are listed, but you can't know the e-mail address of the buyer.